# Is it possible to use iCloud to register or sign on users into an app?

Tags: ios, ios7, single-sign-on, icloud

To solve the problem of creating yet another account, many apps use a Facebook or Twitter single sign on solution.

With iOS 7 is it now possible to use a user's iCloud account as a sign on solution?

I've found a few places that mention it being possible but haven't found anything in the Apple documentation to support those comments.

Comment: Maybe they mean [Game Center](http://www.apple.com/game-center/)? "Just tap the Game Center icon on your Home screen, sign in with your Apple ID, and you’re good to go."

Comment: What are you using user accounts for in you app? And do you only need a user identifier to make an account for them?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for that suggestion, it's possible they did. I actually hadn't thought of adding Game Center support.

Comment: @Hejazi We need to ensure (or try our best) that users are unique, and  also that users can use our app across multiple devices with access to the activities they've already completed on 1 device.

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to ensure that users are unique and they can access their data on all their devices, then yes, you can use iCloud for this.

You can store the app data on iCloud, and the data will be synced to all user's devices (as long as iCloud is enabled in general and for your app, and the logged in user is the same on all devices).

But notice that you still can't get any info about the user account (Apple account) used to login to iCloud. Though, you can store a randomly generated user id on iCloud if you want to differentiate the users by some unique ids.

Comment: Thanks Hejazi, that succinctly sums up everything I needed to know about the subject.